# Spark handle json with dynamically named subschema

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file in the following structure:

```json
{
    "10712": {
        "id": "10712",
        "age": 27,
        "gender": "male"
    },
    "217": {
        "id": "217",
        "age": 60,
        "gender": "female"
    }
}
```

This causes a problem when importing using `spark.read.json`, because of the inconsistency in the schema: `(10712, 217, etc.)`.

I'm trying to always replace the first JSON level with the string "user", like so:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "10712",
        "age": 27,
        "gender": "male"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "217",
        "age": 60,
        "gender": "female"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it would be also be fine to simply remove that schema level, to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "10712",
        "age": 27,
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "id": "217",
        "age": 60,
        "gender": "female"
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `stack() + groupBy() + collect_list()` functions to unnest the top level struct and recreate the struct by changing the name of the top level field.

**`Example:`**

```
df.printSchema()
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json_string]), multiLine=True)

#get the column names and add backtick to the names
cols = [ f"`{i}`" for i in df.columns]

#get the columns length of the dataframe
col_len = len(cols)
stack_expr = ','.join(cols)
df.select(expr(f"stack({col_len},{stack_expr})")).\
  groupBy(lit(1)).\
    agg(to_json(collect_list(col("col0"))).alias("user")).drop("1").\
      show(10,False)

#get columns data into rows and perform groupby with collect_list
df.select(expr(f"stack({col_len},{stack_expr})")).\
  groupBy(lit(1)).\
    agg(collect_list(col("col0")).alias("user")).drop("1").\
      printSchema()
```

**`Output:`**

```
#input
root
 |-- 10712: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 217: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)

#dataframe after groupBy
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"age":27,"gender":"male","id":"10712"},{"age":60,"gender":"female","id":"217"}]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

#schema of the dataframe
root
 |-- user: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file_path.json", "r") as f:   
    json_string = f.read()
    json_as_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    list_of_dicts = list(json_as_dict.values())
    df = spark.createDataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: Why don't you explain code a bit more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, please ensure that your code is free of basic syntax errors when submitting code.