# exploding the struct with no arrays pyspark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jsonparser

I have json data like

```
{
"labels1":
     {"A":1,"B":2, "C":3},
"labels2":
     {"A":1,"B":2, "C":3},
}
```

and I want 3 output columns that say tagname, keyname,value. The final output will be like

```
tagname,key,value
labels1,A,1
labels1,B,2
labels1,C,3
labels2,A,1
labels2,B,2
labels2,C,3
```

How can I achieve this usecase, also the keys A,B,C are just sample and there can be multiple optional fields. Thanks in advance and let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with inbuilt pyspark functions for this case like `stack` and **unnest** the struct to add as new columns.

**`Example:`**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
json = """{"labels1":{"A":1,"B":2, "C":3},"labels2":{"A":1,"B":2, "C":3}}"""
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json]), multiLine=True)
df.select(expr("stack(2,'labels1',labels1,'labels2',labels2)")).\
  select(col("col0").alias("tagname"),col("col1.*")).\
  select("tagname",expr("stack(3,'A',A,'B',B,'C',C) as (key,value)")).show()

#+-------+---+-----+
#|tagname|key|value|
#+-------+---+-----+
#|labels1|  A|    1|
#|labels1|  B|    2|
#|labels1|  C|    3|
#|labels2|  A|    1|
#|labels2|  B|    2|
#|labels2|  C|    3|
#+-------+---+-----+
```

---

Another way by using **`unpivot`** function:

```py
df.withColumn("n",lit(1)).\
  unpivot("n",["labels1", "labels2"],"new","new1").select(col("new").alias("tagname"),col("new1.*")).\
  unpivot("tagname",["A","B","C"],"key","value").\
  show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, but the issue is I have given only sample data. The keys A,B,C... can be optional and many more keys can be there sometimes. I have edited the question too now. Could you let me know how should I approach in that case.

Comment: you can create dynamic stack statement based on `df.columns` as explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314739/7632695

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it worked!! Also do you think if there is any other way possible.

Comment: AFAIK i think these are the possible ways, u may try with melt function from pyspark and i believe that is same as unpivot as mentioned in the answer!